# Material Autocomplete: Link multiple text inputs to one autocomplete panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

**Question**:

How to link multiple text inputs to one [autocomplete panel](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)?

**Use-case**

Given a form with several coupled fields: phone number (`<input>`); phone  description/label (`<input [matAutocomplete]>`). The user should choose one of previously entered phone  description/label.

**Technical challenge**

As per [official example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview), both the `<mat-autocomplete>` and the `<input>` must refer to each other, e.g.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

If such elements are generated in a loop, e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as index">
    ...
</div>
```

when there is no way to generate `mat-autocomplete` IDs dynamically.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If all you want to do is **link multiple input fields to one autocomplete panel**, it's as simple as this - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqktlf)

Markup

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngFor="let autoComplete of autoCompletes">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto ="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

Code

```
export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  autoCompletes = ['batman', 'superman'];
}
```

Or do you want to have multiple input field/autocomplete panel pairs? That would have to be done within the template as template variables are static-only.

Comment: Sure, it's simple as. Thank you for your comprehensive answer with a code sample. I had another issue which caused funky behaviour with the autocomplete and your answer pointed that the problem is somewhere else :)